# Are there any Cordova calendar plugins that work on iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

Does there exist a Cordova calendar plugin that works on iOS and Android? Also, what are the strengths/weaknesses of the calendar plugins? If no plugins exist for Android and iOS, what do you recommend?

All I want to do is read the native calendar events. I do not want to create events, nor do I want to render a calendar in my app. All I want is the data from all of the events from a particular day.

Comment: Did you ever find any working one? The struggle is real.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a plugin already but checkout [TimeSquare for iOS](https://github.com/square/objc-TimesSquare) and [for Android](https://github.com/square/android-times-square). You can make a plugin for this easily.